# MYSQL print some value if the date time crosses certain time

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to print 13 if the from date time value has a particular time i.e., suppose fom date is 12-07-2022 09:15:00am and the to date is 13-07-2022 10:00:00 am as the from date has 12-07-2022 07:00:00pm and till the end date.
I have to print 13 if it is the entire day, from 12-07-2022 06:00:00 pm to 13-07-2022 09:00:00 am and print 26 if the dates are from 12-07-2022 06:00:00 pm to 14-07-2022 09:00:00 am and print.

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>From Date</th>
<th>To Date</th>
<th>No work</th>
<th>Work</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>2022-07-13 09:26</td>
<td>2022-07-15 17:56</td>
<td>26</td>
<td>56.50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2022-07-13 09:26</td>
<td>2022-07-14 17:56</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>32.50</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In the above snippet,in first row, from date and to date is a whole day that is from date time passes 06 pm of that day and the difference between from and to date is 1 day, so I have to print 13 in no work hours where as in the second row I need to print 26 as from date to to date difference is 2 days and the from date crosses 6pm.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you show your expected result in tabular format?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I have edited my question! Please refer that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start, end)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to get the number of hours between two date/time stamps. (Substituting DAY for HOUR will get the number of 24 hour days.) So, something like this gets you the number of hours between two values.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2022-07-12 18:00:00', '2022-07-14 09:00:00')
```

Notice that you must, when specifying date/time constants as text strings, use the format I have shown. You can use [STR_TO_DATE(input, format)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert arbitrarily formatted date/time constants to the ones you want.

Your question didn't give enough information about how you must generate values like `13` or `26` for me to suggest anything about that.

Comment: I have edited my question! please refer it again! Thank you